# tar utility, PHP and exec

Tags: php, exec, tar

Consider the following code

```
echo "tar -cvf $outpath -C $path $file<br>";
$arr = array();
$val = exec("tar -cvf $outpath -C $path $file", $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

`echo` outputs `tar -cvf ../folder/subfolder1/1234.tar -C ../folder/ subfolder2` and this command really create archive if I call it from command line from htdocs folder. However exec do nothing. `var_dump($arr)` prints empty array. So here are the questions

1. How can I make `exec` create archive?
2. Why empty array is outputed?

**UPD.** please note, that I'm running windows.

Comment: `shell_exec('....')` maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173443/php-shell-tar-problem-return-code-2

Comment: @DrColossos,`shell_exec` outputs nothing as well :(

Answer (score 3):

For those who'll read this question: adding `2>&1` to command helped. And I used `shell_exec` instead of sheel

```
$val = shell_exec("tar -cvf $outpath -C $path $file 2>&1");
echo "$val"; // prints output from tar
```